# detecting pattern using machine learning algorithms

Tags: design-patterns, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I was reading an article about reverse engineering of design patterns, and the authors of the article refereed to that it's hard to detect the adapter and strategy patterns using machine learning algorithms **because these patterns have concrete definitions on their realization in code structure and system behavior**. Can anyone describe in more details why machine learning algorithm can't detect such patterns.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you link the article? Do you have machine learning background?

Comment: Plus 1 for a link to the article